Unable to connect wallet using ether.js
I'm currently having problem to connect to my wallet. This is the error:
evmAsk.js:7 Error: Unexpected error
    at Um.<anonymous> (evmAsk.js:7:4197)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at s (evmAsk.js:1:1455)

This is my code using React:
import { useState } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";

const Home = () => {
    const [walletAddress, setWalletAddress] = useState('');
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

    const connectWallet = async () => {
        if (window.ethereum) {
            try {
                // Request account access
                await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });

                // Create a new Web3 provider
                const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);

                // Get the signer
                const signer = provider.getSigner();

                // Get the user's wallet address
                const address = await signer.getAddress();

                // Set the wallet address in state
                setWalletAddress(address);
                setErrorMessage(''); // Clear any previous error messages
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error connecting to MetaMask:", error);
                setErrorMessage("Failed to connect to MetaMask. Please try again.");
            }
        } else {
            alert('MetaMask is not installed. Please install it to use this app.');
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="app flex flex-col items-center pt-7">
            <h1 className="">Connect wallet testing 123 (/≧▽≦)/</h1>
            <button className="border border-gray-300 p-2 rounded-lg" onClick={connectWallet}>
                Connect MetaMask Wallet
            </button>
            {walletAddress && (
                <p className="mt-4">Connected Wallet Address: {walletAddress}</p>
            )}
            {errorMessage && (
                <p className="mt-4 text-red-500">{errorMessage}</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;

I asked copilot and it said it could be the MetaMask conection, ethers library or the way the asynchronous code is handled. I'm honestly new into this and didnt manage to solve this and quite confused.

This happened to me when calling eth_requestAccounts on my window.ethereum object, which I was expecting to be Metamask.
I noticed that the evmAsk.js file was actually part of the phantom wallet I had installed previously.
Disabling phantom wallet temporarily allowed me to get this working via metamask as expected.
Will update my answer if I find another workaround that doesn't require disabling phantom.

This answer helped me, in my case disabling phanthom worked.

I just had this issue on chrome, and fresh installed metamask on firefox with a new wallet and it seems to have worked.

I still have the same on firefox and chrome... nothing is helping
